# How do you create a new subsubsection numbering

Tags: sectioning, subsection

So I have this subsection but It doesn't have a number how do I make it so that it would be like this:

```
chapter 1 

section 1.1

subsection 1.1.1

subsubsection 1.1.1.a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust `secnumdepth` to the level of the sectional unit (level 3 in this case, which denotes up to `\subsubsection`). You can also consider updating `tocdepth` (to level 3, say) to include the `\subsubsection`s in the ToC:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection}}% Recursive numbering for \subsubsection
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}% Show section numbers up to \subsubsection (level 3)
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}% Show sectional units up to \subsubsection (level 3) in ToC
 
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but how do you make it compatible with
` \titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
`
as it doesn't work on them

Comment: @Anon That is a new question. You did not provide an MWE so how was anyone to know how you specified `\subsubsection` format? Please next time provide an MINIMAL WE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`)